# How to get value of an hidden input from PHP Foreach loop with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have tried to get the value of hidden input from the PHP loop using javascript when its input is out focus and it returns all array of values and when I change code some, it returns only the first value.

Here is a PHP for each loop.

```
<?php
 $s = 0;
 foreach ($examSchedule as $key => $student) { ?>
 <input type="hidden" id="student" name="student[]" value="<?php echo 
  $student['student_id'] ?>">
  <?php }
?>
```

And it returns inputs like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="student" name="student[]" value="388">
<input type="hidden" id="student" name="student[]" value="389">
<input type="hidden" id="student" name="student[]" value="390">
<input type="hidden" id="student" name="student[]" value="391">
<input type="hidden" id="student" name="student[]" value="392">
<input type="hidden" id="student" name="student[]" value="393">
```

When I try to get the value I got the array with all the values

```
$("input").focusout(function(event){
 event.preventDefault(); 
var students= $('[name="student[]"]').map(function () {
    return this.value;
    });
 console.log(students);
}
```

Results are

```
n.fn.init(6) ["388", "389", "390", "391", "392", "393", prevObject: 
n.fn.init(6), context: document]
```

And when i try to use

```
$("input").focusout(function(event){
 event.preventDefault(); 
var students = $('#student').val();
console.log(student);
}
```

It just display only the first value.

How can I get the value of specific input when the out focus event is applied to a certain input field.

Comment: `id` attributes have to be unique, so your HTML is invalid and that's why it only ever retrieves the first value. Also it should be `.val()`, not `.val`

Comment: How can i add the unique dynamic id's to these inputs

Comment: Do you really need to? The array you build from the values doesn't use the `id` at all. A common class should be enough for most use cases. What exactly do you do with the `id` values?

Comment: I need these value so as I can update the database table when the focus is out of that touched field, so I can use the value as a reference

Comment: So how is it working now if all the `id` values are the same?

Comment: It doesn't work that's why I like to know a way to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Use "this" keyword in javascript code:

*"this" keyword will provide you the input element on which "focusout" event occurs*

```
$("input").focusout(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var students = $(this).val();
    console.log(student);
}
```